# Android Studio creating keystore error

Tags: java, android-studio, android-keystore

I want to Generate Signed APK via Android Studio. It's my first app so I need to create new Keystore. But when I fill textboxes and click "OK", error appears (message bellow). Keystore is exported, but showed error scares me to use it.

"Key was created with errors:
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M"

Comment: Did you find any issues using that key store ? I am also facing the same issue..

Comment: Yes. Here's how to: press Windows + Pause key at once, click "Advanced system settings", click "Environment variables", and delete the "_JAVA_OPTIONS" line.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue while making signed APK. I had deleted _JAVA_OPTIONS from environment variables and also restart android studio.But I found this error comes because I have set the wrong **keystore path**. So make sure you have set right **keystore path** along with keystore name.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete _JAVA_OPTIONS env variable and try again.

`unset _JAVA_OPTIONS && android-studio`