# How to fix app not installed [Android Studio]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

### Problem

**App not installed** shows when installing signed apk.
The Application will install without any problem for the first time, later if I uninstall and try to reinstall the same apk  it shows **`App not installed`**

### Tried the following things

- Tried only with V1 signature
- Tried only with V2 signature
- Tried with both with V1 and V2 signature
- Changed Build Variant to `Release`
- Tried on 3 different devices
- Uninstalled previous version from the device(for all users) and release folder
- Removed cache memory of the smartphone.

### Note :

I had error a while creating keystore `Key was created with errors: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M` last week but this was solved. But it was resolved by deleting `_JAVA_OPTIONS` from environment variables (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57556572/6088883)
I think after this the started.

### No Problem with codes

I am 100% sure that it's not a problem in the code Because of I tried making signed apk for the basic login activity application. didn't change a single line of code. But the result was same

### Tried the following thread

1. [How to fix App not installed error in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608783/how-to-fix-app-not-installed-error-in-android)
2. [How to Fix Android App Not Installed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51656350/how-to-fix-android-app-not-installed-error)
3. [App not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960863/app-not-installed)
4. [Is there any way to fix APP not installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52313922/is-there-any-way-to-fix-app-not-installed) (Exact same issue)

**None of them solved the issue**

### Temporary fix

The only method working was disabling **Google Play Protect** (which is not a proper fix)

Comment: Is there any Sensitive permissions you are asking? like Admin App?

Comment: No, Only permission used is for **sending SMS**. 
[Here](https://github.com/Mayoogh/SimpleSMSSender/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) is my Manifest.xml

Comment: SMS permission might not be granted to malicious apps, no matter what the manifest says.

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html

Comment: @MayuriK No, I will check it and will let you know

Comment: Also which Android OS version are you using ?

Comment: @MayuriK Windows10

Comment: @MayuriK As per the [post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html) I added ``android:testOnly="false"`` to my Manifest.
Even tried [this one](https://gist.github.com/xujiaao/5fd127a72979cdc3c70dcc1324786f87)
``android.injected.testOnly=false`` in gradle.properties .But no positive result

Comment: I have tried your code and it's running without any problems. There might be something wrong with your mobile or device.

Comment: @GreenROBO I have tried the same with 3 different devices

Comment: Try Invalidate cache and restart for your android studio. It will remove any cached signatures on your device.

Comment: @MayuriK Yes, But nothing positive.

Comment: @MayooghGirish Did you find a solution?

Comment: @KRK Not yet. I even tried installing Android Studio on my Linux and had the same error. I have [submitted an appeal at Play Protect](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals)
. Waiting for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Just try adding Action VIEW in manifest file.
After this, reinstall the app and the problem will be solved.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>

         // add this line of code in application tag  only single line of code will also work
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    </intent-filter>


</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if the application is installed for multiple users. You should uninstall for all users. There are 2 ways to do that.

- From the terminal/ shell: `adb uninstall` or `adb uninstall [package_name]`
- Uninstall for all users(you need to be admin user):

  1. Open Settings and then Apps
  2. Open the app info
  3. Open the overflow menu (3 vertical dots)
  4. Choose Uninstall for all users.

Comment: I already tried that one.
Please see **Tried the following things** in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but still is anyone find it time-saving.

None of the solutions were working for me and there were no changes except asset file changes. Wasted a lot of time over a silly issue. (Clean and rebuild project did not solve it for me)

Try File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I saw this behavior as well, and it was not because there was a previous version of the app installed nor was it a corrupted or bad apk file, nor a min Android version not met. Although I have been able to install unsigned apk files on my devices in the past (w/ developer options and allowing unknown sources of course),  I noticed that certain apps MUST BE SIGNED even with all the permissions relaxed to allow unsigned unknown apps. My app was an IME (i.e a keyboard app), and it seems the sensitive nature of IMEs require them to be signed no matter what.